# events in databound listview running really slowly on published site asp.net

Tags: asp.net, performance, listview

I have a databound listview, with some controls in it. They are just image buttons. When i run in local debug mode, thy run smoothly and the code does not take forever to run.

However. When i publish the site, and code that runs as a consequence of me pressing an image button in the listview; runs really slowly. And does not fully execute for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume page reloading is your issue. If so adding the list view and the contents to be updated into an Ajax update panel may solve the issue. Make a try. Also remember to place the controls in a ContentTemplate and to add a script manager

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. The problem was that it was loading too much data on that one page. Therefore rendering it very slow; thanks for the feedback anyway!